# Rails 5.1 api webpacker and vuejs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, webpacker, manifest.json

I'm trying to create a Rails API and a client in VueJs using webpacker on Cloud9.

After a standard installation : `npm install -g yarn && rails _5.1.4_ new . --api --webpack=vue`

I'm using **Foreman** to launch rails and webpack, here is the file.

```
# Procfile.dev
web: bundle exec rails s -p $PORT -b $IP
webpacker: ./bin/webpack-dev-server --inline true --hot true --public $C9_HOSTNAME
```

I changed the development part of `config/webpacker.yml` to this :

```
development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
  dev_server:
    https: false
    host: localhost
    port: 8081
```

When launching `foreman start` the webpack creates `public/packs/manifest.json` containing the follow object.

```
{
  "application.js": "/packs/application-d2ce57fea2210882a7d4.js",
  "hello_vue.css": "/packs/hello_vue-9cb5a7334a6577c3422968b9b9970b2f.css",
  "hello_vue.js": "/packs/hello_vue-d8d50a7562d6abcbea06.js"
}
```

I created a `public/index.html` file containing the following

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="packs/hello_vue-9cb5a7334a6577c3422968b9b9970b2f.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="packs/application-d2ce57fea2210882a7d4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="packs/hello_vue-bd484161b1956b3a536b.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now when I go to the URL I have the `Hello World from Webpacker` in my JavaScript console and the `Hello Vue!` in the browser.

My question is : Is it possible to use this generated `manifest.json` to automatically launch the good files (js, css) and how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a plugin called [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) that can create the `index.html` file with all the good css and js links.

I just had to `npm install html-webpack-plugin --save-dev` and then modify my `config/webpack/development.js` like this :

```
const environment = require('./environment')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

environment.plugins.prepend('HtmlWebpackPlugin', new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  title: 'My Vuejs App',
  inject: true
}))

module.exports = environment.toWebpackConfig()
```

Comment: This was helpful.  Was difficult to determine which file in Webpacker was the same as the Webpack docs, and the syntax was a bit different.

One note: for **Webpack 4** `.set()` is  **now replaced with `.prepend()`**, so the code above is correct, but you should do:

`environment.plugins.prepend('HtmlWebpackPlugin', new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  title: 'My Vuejs App',
  inject: true
}))`